# Baking physics doesn't display

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, baking

From what I've seen, to bake physics you have a rigid body object in the scene and go the the "Blender Game Renderer" and press <kbd>P</kbd>. When I do this, physics fall and everything properly. However, when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go back to editing or whatever, the physics aren't there (when scrubbing through keyframes). Here's a video for help: https://youtu.be/I2S8cX7LVDY

Here's one of the cell fractures rigid body settings:
[image: rigid body settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do this in BGE.

In object mode select your physic object or objects then in the *Tools Panel* select *Physics* and *Bake To Keyframes*.

[image: bake]

### Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Using "Bake to Keyframes" does not work correctly. The object just remains still when scrubbing through. The settings for baking are default.

Comment: Do you need this to be done in BGE? In my case Rigid Body is done in Cycles Render.

Comment: I've been trying in both BGE and Cycles.

Comment: Check blend file in my update.

Comment: Your blend file worked fine. I scrapped my project and retried, now physics work fine. Not sure what happened there.

Comment: Probably it's from switching between BGE and Cycles, maybe some options left somewhere. I'm glad I could help.